# Tweepy - Check if update_status was successful or get failure reason

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, tweepy

I've got a piece of code that should send a tweet with `tweepy`. Occasionally it's failing to send the tweet for some unbeknownst reason, the API keys are valid, it's only possibly sending a tweet every hour or two max, and the tweets aren't duplicated. How do I check if the `update_status` method from tweepy completed successfully and/or get the reason it failed.

The code currently is

```
    try:
        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
        auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
        api = tweepy.API(auth)
        api.update_status(tweet)
    except Exception as e:
        print("TwitterError: " + str(e))
```

Comment: That is pretty wide net of exceptions you are catching, are you able to look back at what `print` gives?

Comment: @salparadise Prints not generating anything, it's not creating an exception it's just "silently failing" which is something update_status can do according to the docs.

Comment: from the docs "> or too long will be silently ignored."  you checked the length as a possible issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**
Use exception handling provided by the tweepy module `tweepy.TweepError`

```
try:
    if api.update_status(tweet):
        print("Posted")
except tweepy.error.TweepError as e:
    print(e)
```

[Read the docs](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html#tweepy-error-exceptions)

Comment: What ugly stack trace?

Comment: Is TweepError actually going to display it though as the update_status docs state that it can potentially "silently fail"

Comment: Yes, It will display the error, I have tested with above limit chars  and I got this result: `[{'code': 186, 'message': 'Status is over 140 characters.'}]` You can explore it more